# PowerShell Connecting To Office 365 from Module

Tags: powershell, office365

I have created a PowerShell Module. Each function in the module has it's own script file so I can keep track of them.

I have a problem with the function below:

```
function Connect-O365
{
  $global:o365Cred = Get-Credential
  $global:o365Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell -Credential $global:o365Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -Verbose

  Import-PSSession $global:o365Session -Verbose -AllowClobber
  Connect-MsolService –Credential $global:o365Cred -Verbose

  Get-Mailbox    # SEE BELOW
}
```

When I call the function it goes through all the motions and appears to run correctly. No errors are shown. However when I call teh get-mailbox function I get an error that the 'command or cmdlet does not exist'.

If I execute each line of code on the command line it works fine. If I add the function to my PowerShell profile it also works fine. I also added the Get-Mailbox line to the end of it (as next to the comment # SEE BELOW) and it displays the mailboxes.

What it looks like to me is something to do with scope. As soon as this is put into a module function it stops working as it should. As soon as it runs and exits the commands that I'm needing disappear.

I have tried making the function global but that doesn't work either.

Does anybody have any suggestions?